# Change "Choice field" type in Word document Content Type

Tags: content-type, choice-field

I have a Word document Content Type on a Document Library. I'm adding SharePoint columns as fields to the document:

[image]

One of the columns called "Initial_ReportType" is a Choice column which is configured as "Radio Buttons".

When I add "Initial_ReportType" to the Word document it appears as a drop-down menu:

[image]

How do I change "Initial_ReportType" to a Radio Buttons field (in the Word document) like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is not possible. If you open XML Mapping pane under Developer tab (needs to be added in the [options](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/show-the-developer-tab-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45)), radio button for inserting mapped control is not available.

[image: XML Mapping of controls]

Comment: Thanks I wasn’t aware of this option. I still could not change it but you’ve taught me something new :)